# Integration property proof (upper and lower Riemann Integral)

Tags: calculus, integration

Consider $f: I =[a_1,b_1]\times...\times[a_n,b_n]\subset R^n\to R^n$ I have to prove the following property:

$f$ is integrable $\Longleftrightarrow \int_\underline{I} f=\int_\overline{I}f $

(Sorry for the notation, I mean the upper Riemann integral and the lower Riemann integral must be the same).

$\int_\underline{I} f= sup \{L(P,f)\}$, where $L(P,F)=\sum_{k=1}^nm_kc(J_k)$ and $m_k=inf_{x_k\in J_k}f(x_k)$

$\int_\overline{I}f = inf \{U(P,f)\}$, where $U(P,F)=\sum_{k=1}^nM_kc(J_k)$ and $M_k=sup_{x_k\in J_k}f(x_k)$

The definition I have to use for integrability is the following:

$f$ is integrable $\Longleftrightarrow \forall\epsilon>0,\exists P_\epsilon$ a partition of $ I|P\succeq P_\epsilon, |S(P,f)-\int_If|<\epsilon $

($S(P,f)=\sum_{k=1}^nf(x_k)c(J_k)| x_k\in J_k$)

$J_k$ is each "block" or "cell" of $I$

I have no idea to prove any of the two implications.

Thank you for your help and time.

Comment: Could you clarify your notation a little bit, especially what are $J_k$ and $P_{\epsilon}$. If I had to guess I would say that $P_{\epsilon}$ is a partition of your interval, and $J_k$ is in the partition?

Comment: The upper and lower definition is for real-valued functions only.  Not for values in $R^n$.

Comment: I've made some changes. I hope it is clearer now. @GEdgar, I think we can extend this concept to $R^n$ too, using the notation above.

Comment: You mention $m_k = \inf_{x_k \in I_k} f(x_k)$, but I do not know what that means when $f$ has values in $R^n$.  Only when it has values in $R$.

Comment: Neither do I. We use this notation in class but I am pretty lost